# in angularjs how to access the element that triggered the event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use both Bootstrap and AngularJS in my web app. I'm having some difficulty getting the two to work together.

I have an element, which has the attribute `data-provide="typeahead"`

```
<input id="searchText" ng-model="searchText" type="text"
       class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="title"
       data-provide="typeahead" ng-change="updateTypeahead()" />
```

And I want to update the `data-source` attribute when the user inputs in the field. The function `updateTypeahead` is triggered correctly, but I don't have access to the element that triggered the event, unless I use `$('#searchText')`, which is the jQuery way, not the AngularJS way.

What is the best way to get AngularJS to work with old style JS module.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
 updateTypeahead(this)
```

will not pass DOM element to the function `updateTypeahead(this)`. Here `this` will refer to the scope. <s>If you want to access the DOM element use `updateTypeahead($event)`. In the callback function you can get the DOM element by `event.target`.</s>

> Please Note : ng-change function doesn't allow to pass $event as variable.

Comment: ng-change does not support event object $event being passed as a parameter.

Comment: ng-style doesn't support either it seems.

Comment: Downvoted too.
Doesn't work for ng-class. $event got undefined !
```<li ng-repeat="item in items" role="menuitem" ng-class="{\'selected\' : isSelected($event, item)}">```

Comment: ng-change does not support this $event style of passing a parameter.  My guess is that it doesn't translate to a natural browser event and therefore there isn't one.

Comment: Yeah well, doesn't really answer the question, as $event does not work with ng-change :/

Comment: probably the most over rated answer ever seen on SO

Answer (score 77):

The general Angular way to get access to an element that triggered an event is to write a directive and bind() to the desired event:

```
app.directive('myChange', function() {
  return function(scope, element) {
    element.bind('change', function() {
      alert('change on ' + element);
    });
  };
});
```

or with DDO (as per @tpartee's comment below):

```
app.directive('myChange', function() {
  return { 
    link:  function link(scope, element) {
      element.bind('change', function() {
        alert('change on ' + element);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The above directive can be used as follows:

```
<input id="searchText" ng-model="searchText" type="text" my-change>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QcxS7Ta3U7mHmlcGAtac?p=preview).

Type into the text field, then leave/blur.  The change callback function will fire.  Inside that callback function, you have access to `element`.

Some built-in directives support passing an $event object.  E.g., ng-*click, ng-Mouse*.  Note that ng-change does not support this event.

Although you can get the element via the $event object:

```
<button ng-click="clickit($event)">Hello</button>

$scope.clickit = function(e) {
    var elem = angular.element(e.srcElement);
    ...
```

this goes "deep against the Angular way" -- [Misko](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/SYglWP_x7ew/lFtb75NWNWUJ).

Comment: While your solution sort of works, it doesn't use DDO format, which makes it very, very confusing to figure out how to add/pass scope to the binding. There's no simple way from your example to simply add some DDO sugar for scoping and that seems just as deeply "against the Angular way" as passing $event from an ng-click. In fact in the official Angular documentation and code examples, I could find not a single example which is syntactically similar to yours (i.e. a directive returning only an anonymous function without any DDO).

Comment: @tpartee, good points.  Back when I originally wrote this answer, the angular docs did have examples of simple directives that just returned an anonymous function (which is the link function).  I agree that a DDO would be better these days.  I updated the answer.

Comment: I think <button ng-click="clickit($event.srcElement)"> would be better

Comment: As time goes on, I'm more and more convinced that "the Angular way" is overarchitected and overcomplicated

Answer (score 8):

you can get easily like this first **write event on element**

```
ng-focus="myfunction(this)"
```

and **in your js file** like below

```
$scope.myfunction= function (msg, $event) {
    var el = event.target
    console.log(el);
}
```

I have used it as well.

Comment: this returns the scope, so this won't work as expected.

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's issue at all. Sure it lets one function know who the called is, but that has no bearing on the ng-change call and there's no connection between the two. What the OP needs is to be able to reference the element which triggered the ng-change event within the function call it makes.

Comment: This works by adding the attributes (say, id): alert(event.target.id).

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution using $element in the controller if you don't want to create another directive for this problem:

```
appControllers.controller('YourCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$element',
        function($scope, $timeout, $element) {

    $scope.updateTypeahead = function() {
       // ... some logic here
       $timeout(function() {
           $element[0].getElementsByClassName('search-query')[0].focus();
           // if you have unique id you can use $window instead of $element:
           // $window.document.getElementById('searchText').focus();
       });
    }
}]);
```

And this will work with **ng-change**:

```
<input id="searchText" type="text" class="search-query" ng-change="updateTypeahead()" ng-model="searchText" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna ng-model value, if you can write like this in the triggered event:
$scope.searchText

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version you had, but this question was asked for long time ago. Currently with Angular 1.5, I can use the `ng-keypress` event and `debounce` function from [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/) to emulate similar behavior like `ng-change`, so I can capture the $event

```
<input type="text" ng-keypress="edit($event)" ng-model="myModel">
```

> $scope.edit = _.debounce(function ($event) {
>           console.log("$event", $event)
>       }, 800)