# Get element that has focus from ngFocus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to get the innerHTML of the element that triggers a ngFocus or ngBlur?

```
<textarea ng-focus="focus()"></textarea>
```

then in my controller I have

```
$scope.focus = function() {
    //I need innerHTML here of the textarea that triggered me
}
```

Comment: why don't use `ng-model` that will hold the value on whatever inside the `textarea`

Comment: if I have multiple textareas created from a ng-repeat and I want to do something with what's inside the textarea when focused. I can't use ng-model.

Comment: could you add that html too?

Answer (score 1):

```
focus(this)
```

will not pass DOM element to the function `focus(this)`. Here `this` will refer to the scope. If you want to access the DOM element use `focus($event)`. In the callback function you can get the DOM element by `event.target`

> **Source copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/13000154**

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-model` on that text area. So while `ng-focus` event gets fired you could get that value from `scope` of the controller easily.